# p tags are not removed in for loop with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, django, regex, beautifulsoup, tags

I'm trying to remove some marks from text, like `<p>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n</p>` and `<p>\r\n</p>`

here is code where I am using here BeautifulSoup.

```
        article = Article.objects.all()

        for obj in article:
            soup_en = BeautifulSoup(obj.text_en, features="html5lib")
            obj.text_en = '\n'.join(map(str, OrderedSet(soup_en.find_all('p')))).replace(r'\r\n', '').replace('#####444#####', '').replace('#####555#####', '').replace('<p></p>', '').replace(r'<p>&nbsp;</p>', '')
            obj.save()
```

Text with marks to remove:

```
<p>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n</p>

<p>\r\n</p>

<p>Name of person </p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>\r\n</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>\r\n</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

Everything is ok when I am dealing only with one object for example `obj = Article.objects.get(old_id=50)`
But when I putted code into for loop, then I found in text strange result, I mean some parts are double (`<p>Name of person </p>`) and at the begining of text is mark

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>Name of person </p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Name of person </p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

Comment: try the code `text = re.sub(r'<p>[\r\n\s]*</p>','',text )`

Comment: you should call `.text()` on each element that bs found which gives you only the text and removes any HTML element.

Comment: could you tell us what `obj.text_en` looks like and what you expect it to look like afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `obj.text_en` looks like-

```html
<p>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>\r\n</p>

<p>#####444#####</p>

<p>#####555#####</p>

<p>Name of person </p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>\r\n</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>\r\n</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

Which should cover all the cases you seem to be trying to replace.

Now, the stuff like the CRLF and `&nbsp;` can be easily gotten rid of by doing `strip` on `.text` of each element.

The stuff like `####444####`, are best to be handled with regex.

Accordingly, if we had the html like so-

```py
html = """<p>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>\r\n</p>

<p>#####444#####</p>

<p>#####555#####</p>

<p>Name of person </p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>\r\n</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>\r\n</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>"""
```

This is what you'd need-

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
# The following regex matches either empty strings (`''`) or patterns such as `#####555#####`
BAD_PATTERN = re.compile(r'^(?:|#{5}\d{3}#{5})$')
paras = soup.find_all('p')
# Join all the "good" strings with a newline
content = '\n'.join([item for item in map(lambda x: x.text.strip(), paras) if not BAD_PATTERN.match(item)])
print(content)
```

Output-

> Name of person
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

What it does, and how it does-

- First off, this regex `^(?:|#{5}\d{3}#{5})$` - will match either empty strings (`''`) or patterns like `#####555#####`. That is, 5 hashtags, followed by 3 digits, followed by 5 hashtags.

  Check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/57fx4F/1)
- `map(lambda x: x.text.strip(), paras)` will return a map object, where each element is simply the text, stripped of whitespace characters, of each `p` element.
- We then iterate through that `map` and create a list consisting of **only the text that DOES NOT match the previously mentioned pattern**.

  `[item for item in map(lambda x: x.text.strip(), paras) if not BAD_PATTERN.match(item)]`
- Finally, we join the contents of said list with a `\n`.